# how to get access to network-setting page in iphone

Tags: iphone, networking, setting

I want to get access to the page of network-setting from my own app.
   `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]]`  it works?
I tried but failed. 
Thanks in advance.

I this document : ["Apple URL Scheme Reference"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1/) I found no setting url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was allowed in iOS 5, then disallowed in iOS 5.1. So if you are testing on 5.1 it won't work anymore.

Comment: sigh~I'm on 5.1~so I can't get access at all?Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your question, there is no official URL scheme to access the settings app.

Comment: so, is there any other solution?

Comment: Other than asking your users to make the changes you want, no, not really.